# How can I append images to an existing pdf file in android using itextpdf

Tags: android, itext

I am using the file code to open pdf file in append mode.

```
String FILE = ROOT + "/PDF/" + "DemoLogix.pdf";
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(FILE, true));
document.open();
```

But when I am adding my image using the following code

```
            PdfPTable table5 = new PdfPTable(new float[]{1});
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);  //path is where image is stored.
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream1);
            Image image1 = Image.getInstance(stream1.toByteArray());
            PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(image1, false);
            cell3.setPadding(30);
            cell3.setBorderWidth(0.0f);
            image1.scaleToFit(100, 500);
            image1.setAlignment(image1.ALIGN_RIGHT);
            table5.addCell(cell3);
            document.add(table5);
            document.close();
```

It still doesn't works. Instead it overwrites the previous text. Please someone help me.

Answer (score 2):

Load the PDF you want to modify

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(srcPdf);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(destPdf));
PdfContentByte content = stamper.getOverContent(1);
```

Then, load the image (imagePath is the full path for the imagem file):

```
Image image = Image.getInstance(imagePath);

// scale the image to 50px height
image.scaleAbsoluteHeight(50);
image.scaleAbsoluteWidth((image.getWidth() * 50) / image.getHeight());
```

Since the image dimensions are large, it's scaled to 50 pixels height before we add it to the PDF.

Then set the page coordinates where we want it. Be aware that the 0 value for the Y axis is the bottom of the page, not the top:

```
image.setAbsolutePosition(70, 140);
```

All you need to do now is add it to the page reference and close the stamper:

```
content.addImage(image);
stamper.close();
```

That's it!

Comment: This answer is working. Can you suggest any way in which I can add image at the end of the content.